# Protection against accidental object incompatibility?

Tags: c++, linker, c-preprocessor, symbol-table, misspelling

### TL;DR

Protection against binary incompatibility resulting from compiler argument typos in shared, possibly templated headers' preprocessor directives, which control conditional compilation, in different compilation units?

Ex.

```
g++ ... -DYOUR_NORMAl_FLAG ... -o libA.so
/**Another compilation unit, or even project. **/
g++ ... -DYOUR_NORMA1_FLAG ... -o libB.so
/**Another compilation unit, or even project. **/
g++ ... -DYOUR_NORMAI_FLAG ... main.cpp libA.so //The possibilities!
```

### The Basic Story

Recently, I ran into a strange bug: the symptom was a single SIGSEGV, which always seemed to occur at the same location after recompling. This led me to believe there was some kind of memory corruption going on, and the actual underlying pointer is not a pointer at all, but some data section.

I save you from the long and strenuous journey taking almost two otherwise perfectly good work days to track down the problem. Sufficient to say, Valgrind, GDB, nm, readelf, electric fence, GCC's stack smashing protection, and then some more measures/methods/approaches failed.

In utter devastation, my attention turned to the finest details in the build process, which was analogous to:

- Build one small library.
- Build one large library, which uses the small one.
- Build the test suite of the large library.

Only in case when the large library was used as a static, or a dynamic library dependency (ie. the dynamic linker loaded it automatically, no dlopen)
was there a problem. The test case where all the code of the library was simply included in the tests, everything worked: this was the most important clue.

### The "Solution"

In the end, it turned out to be the simplest thing: a single (!) typo.

Turns out, the compilation flags differed by a single char in the test suite, and the large library: a define, which was controlling the behavior of the small library, was misspelled.
Critical information morsel: the small library had *some* templates. These were used directly in every case, without explicit instantiation in advance. The contents of one of the templated classes changed when the flag was toggled: some data fields were simply not present in case the flag was defined!
The linker noticed nothing of this. (Since the class was templated, the resultant symbols were weak.)
The code used dynamic casts, and the class affected by this problem was inheriting from the mangled class -> things went south.

**My question is as follows: how would you protect against this kind of problem? Are there any tools or solutions which address this specific issue?**

### Future Proofing

I've thought of two things, and believe no protection can be built on the object file level:

- 1: Save options implemented as preprocessor symbols in some well defined place, preferably extracted by a separate build step. Provide check script which uses this to check all compiler defines, and defines in user code. Integrate this check into the build process. Possibly use Levenshtein distance or similar to check for misspellings. Expensive, and the script / solution can get complicated. Possible problem with similar flags (but why have them?), additional files must accompany compiled library code. (Well, maybe with DWARF 2, this is untrue, but let's assume we don't want that.)
- 2: Centralize build options: cheap, customization option left open (think makefile.local), but makes monolithic monstrosities, strong project couplings.

I'd like to go ahead and quench a few likely flame inducing embers possibly flaring up in some readers: "do not use preprocessor symbols" is not an option here.

- Conditional compilation does have it's place in high performance code, and doing everything with templates and enable_if-s would needlessly overcomplicate things. While the above solution is usually not *desirable* it can *arise* form the development process.
- Please assume you have no control over the situation, assume you have legacy code, assume everything you can to force yourself to avoid side-stepping.
- If those won't do, generalize into ABI incompatibility detection, though this might escalate the scope of the question too much for SO.

I'm aware of:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html

  - DT_SONAME is not applicable.
  - Other version schemes therein are not applicable either - they were designed to protect a package which is in itself not faulty.
- [Mixing C++ ABIs to build against legacy libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162444/mixing-c-abis-to-build-against-legacy-libraries)
- [Static analysis tool to detect ABI breaks in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969916/static-analysis-tool-to-detect-abi-breaks-in-c)

Comment: `make` is your friend.

Comment: They are my friends, but unfortunately, the friend of my friend is not necessarily my friend applies, which culminates in makefiles in separate projects silently hating each other.

Answer (score 0):

If it matters, don't have a default case.

```
#ifdef YOUR_NORMAL_FLAG
  // some code
#elsif YOUR_SPECIAL_FLAG
  // some other code
#else
  // in case of a typo, this is a compilation error
#  error "No flag specified"
#endif
```

This may lead to a large list of compiler options if conditional compilation is overused, but there are ways around this like defining config-files

```
flag=normal
flag2=special
```

which get parsed by build scripts and generate the options and can possibly check for typos or could be parsed directly from the Makefile.

Comment: You are hitting the nail with the elimination of the situation in which the lack of information **is** information. This solution evolved into solution number 1 above - what I don't like about this one is the introduction of the extra flag which must be paid attention to. If we are touching the build system, why not attempt to eliminate the need to introduce additional complexity at all?

Comment: In addition I forgot to mention I'd like to keep "negation" behavior as simple as possible. This does not go well with -U for undef - the compiler has no information that the flag is in fact a binary switch, and thus the option loses meaning -> instant error, if not handled explicitly by the build system, which adds another layer of complexity.